# NuGet fails to load PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, nuget

I have a problem similar to the reflector problem, except that I don't have the Reflector plugin installed, and I still can't start the NuGet console. I'm running on Windows 7 Professional, VS 2010 SP1.

Nuget works fine through the GUI, but for instance, I can't install *.vsdoc files without the console.

The following error is:

```
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2943) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2950) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2957) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2964) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2971) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SecurityDescriptorCommandsBase" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: , C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager\1.2.20325.9034\Scripts\NuGet.Types.ps1xml(9) : Error in type "System.__ComObject#{866311e6-c887-4143-9833-645f5b93f6f1}": Exception: Cannot convert the "NuGet.VisualStudio.ProjectExtensions" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: , C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager\1.2.20325.9034\Scripts\NuGet.Types.ps1xml(33) : Error in type "Microsoft.VisualStudio.FSharp.ProjectSystem.Automation.OAProject": Exception: Cannot convert the "NuGet.VisualStudio.ProjectExtensions" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Type".
System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException: Could not load file or assembly 'Scripts\nuget.psm1' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Scripts\nuget.psm1' or one of its dependencies. The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG)) ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path)
at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.<AssemblyPaths>d__1.MoveNext()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.InnerResolveHandler(String name)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.VsAppDomainManager.ResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadBinaryModule(Boolean trySnapInName, String moduleName, String fileName, Assembly assemblyToLoad, String moduleBase, SessionState ss, String prefix, Boolean loadTypes, Boolean loadFormats, Boolean& found)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleNamedInManifest(String moduleName, String moduleBase, Boolean searchModulePath, String prefix, SessionState ss, Boolean loadTypesFiles, Boolean loadFormatFiles, Boolean& found)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModuleManifest(ExternalScriptInfo scriptInfo, ManifestProcessingFlags manifestProcessingFlags, Version version)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ModuleCmdletBase.LoadModule(String fileName, String moduleBase, String prefix, SessionState ss, Boolean& found)
at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand.ProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Pipeline.Invoke()
at NuGetConsole.Host.PowerShell.Implementation.PowerShellHost.Invoke(String command, Object input, Boolean outputResults)
at NuGetConsole.Host.PowerShell.Implementation.PowerShellHostExtensions.ImportModule(PowerShellHost host, String modulePath)
at NuGetConsole.Host.PowerShell.Implementation.PowerShellHost.LoadStartupScripts()
at NuGetConsole.Host.PowerShell.Implementation.PowerShellHost.Initialize()
at NuGetConsole.Implementation.Console.ConsoleDispatcher.Start()
at NuGetConsole.Implementation.PowerConsoleToolWindow.MoveFocus(FrameworkElement consolePane)
```

Comment: See answers in related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457039/nuget-powershell-and-executionpolicy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only solution that worked was to start the PowerShell manually before starting VS2010.

So if anybody had this problem that's the quick fix.

Comment: unbelievably annoying "feature" of powershell. I have the policy set to "Bypass" in the scope of "LocalMachine", yet I was seeing this. Running PS before VS did the trick, thx for saving my day

Answer (score 2):

NuGet needs Powershell2 to work correctly. You can download and install if from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

Comment: Besides not having powershell 2 make sure you are using the latest version of NuGet http://nuget.org/.

Comment: Yes but the error message is pulling from the powershell 1.0 dir :)

Comment: The error message in versions > 1.0 tell you exactly whats wrong :).

Comment: I all ready have installed powershell 2.0 and its latest version of nuget. Those are the first things I've tried.

Comment: Try disabling all of your add-ins. Tools -> Add-in Manager. See if it loads then.

Comment: @MatthewM.Osborn Powershell 2 still installs into the 1.0 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the powershell doesn't help me. I found that this is an known issue of Nuget. You get this issue because you have red gate reflector add-in installed and enabled. If you update Reflector to the latest version (>= 6.5), it should work.

Please take a look at this link

http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/265

Comment: No Reflector add-in was installed. That was the initial problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue under Visual Studio 2012. Neither removing Reflector nor removing GhostDoc extension, which were both said to cause such errors, helped. However, installing Windows Powershell 3.0 came to the rescue:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Productivity power tools was my problem. v12.0.30129.0 I disabled it - an uninstall was not necessary - and vs 2013 worked again