# Installing SignalR from NuGet (problems with Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2013, json.net, signalr, nuget

I'm trying to install SignalR through NuGet. When it comes to install Json it says that the installation is failed because of a PowerShell policy. 
I've found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353951/cant-install-nuget-package-because-of-failed-to-initialize-the-powershell-host)  to explain what to do in such case.

Unfortunately changing the setting is blocked by our company policy and I'm not able to change that value.

What I did as next step is to manually download Json.NET and reference in my project manually. I was hoping that NuGet will find the reference and ignore the installation. But that didn't work as well.

Finally coming to my question: Is there a way to "tell" NuGet to ignore the Json.NET Dependency while installing SignalR ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was about to try what Sirwan suggested until I realized that because of the Execution Policy of PS, I wasn't even able anymore to run any commands in the Package Manager Console.

The Solution:

> You can actually change the MachinePolcy Execution Policy without
>   going through GPO! You need to go in the registry and edit the
>   following key HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell and
>   change the ExecutionPolicy value to ByPass

Solution found [here](http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2014/03/change-powershell-machinepolicy-execution-policy-windows-server-2012r2.html)

That acutally also solves the other problem that I had by installing Json.NET.

Answer (score 1):

The `Install-Package` command has a flag to ignore the dependencies:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -IgnoreDependencies
```

> Install-Package [-Id]  [-IgnoreDependencies] [-ProjectName
>   ] [-Version ] [-Source ] [-IncludePrerelease]
>   [-Force] [-FileConflictAction] [-DependencyVersion
>   ] [-WhatIf]

```
-IgnoreDependencies
        Installs only this package and not its dependencies.

        Required: false
```

[more info.](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console-powershell-reference)

Comment: Hi Sirwan, yes that would work, but then I'm in a Dependency nightmare since the whole SignalR dependency tree consists of quiet a lot packages. Any other possiblity?

Comment: Hi, First of all I suggest you to install `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core` package because it has dependency to JSON.NET, then Install `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`