# The string is missing the terminator: '. - Visual Studio Package Manager Console Error

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2022

When I try to install nuget packages on one of my projects, the installation fails and throws the below error.

[image]

When I try to open the packgae manager console, I can see the console throws the folowing error.

[image]

I have no idea what this error means and where to look at to find the issue.

I tried all the suggestions on this thread but nothing seem to work. I think the error in package manager console might be causign the issue in the first place.

[Can't install nuget package because of "Failed to initialize the PowerShell host"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353951/cant-install-nuget-package-because-of-failed-to-initialize-the-powershell-host?page=1&tab=createdasc#tab-top)

The wierd thing is I only see this error in one specific visual studio solution. If open up another project in different solution, it seems to work fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok. figured it out. It was due to having a space in the project folder path. I moved the project to a folder that has no spaces in the name and it worked.